# Laravel 5.8 authentication

Tags: laravel, authentication

Hi i've a problem with laravel authentication system (5.8) The problem is that I need to login two times to enter my site

My routes file is

```
Route::get('/', 'RefundsController@index');
Route::get('/polizza', 'RefundsController@indexRefunds')->name('polizza');
Auth::routes();

--------------other routes------------------
```

RefundsController

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    
    public function index(){
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    public function indexRefunds(Request $request){
        DB::enableQueryLog(); 
        $grafici = 1;

        $getAverageLiquidati = DB::table('refunds')
            ->select(DB::raw("AVG(DATEDIFF(date_liq, date_ref)) AS avgliq"))
            ->where([
                ['disactive','=', 1],
                ['date_liq','<>','0000-00-00'],
                ['status_ref','>', 5]
                ])
            ->get();

        $getAverageRifiutati = DB::table('refunds')
        ->select(DB::raw("AVG(DATEDIFF(date_status, date_ref)) AS avgrif"))
        ->where(function($q) {
            $q->where('status_ref','=', 2)
              ->orWhere('status_ref','=', 3)
              ->orWhere('status_ref','=', 4);
        })
        ->where([
            ['disactive','=', 1],
            ['date_liq','<>','0000-00-00'],
            ])
        ->get();
        //dd(DB::getQueryLog());
        //dd($getAverageRifiutati);

        return view('pages.modify', compact('grafici','getAverageLiquidati','getAverageRifiutati'));
    }
```

login blade

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Login') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!--<div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{-- old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' --}}>

                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                        {{-- __('Remember Me') --}}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>-->

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Login') }}
                                </button>

                                {{--@if (Route::has('password.request'))--}}
                                    <!--<a class="btn btn-link" href="{{-- route('password.request') --}}">
                                        {{-- __('Forgot Your Password?') --}}
                                    </a>-->
                                {{--@endif--}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

my LoginController

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/polizza';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

In my Middleware

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/polizza');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

When i connect to https://www.example.com/refunds/ because of definition in RefundsController it takes me to https://www.example.com/refunds/login but when i insert credentials it takes me to https://www.example.com/refunds/ with again login form then when i insert credentials it finally takes me to https://www.example.com/refunds/polizza

I dont understand why :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first redirect happens because in your Controller constructor, you are setting the middleware to auth. Hence, all unauthorized requests to any methods in that Controller will be redirected to default log in page. (https://www.example.com/refunds/ redirects to https://www.example.com/refunds/login)

When you enter your credentials there, Laravel takes you to your intended route (the route you tried to access without being authenticated, and that is https://www.example.com/refunds/).

This time you are authenticated, so in your controller, your index method is set to return log in view, so the view is being returned and rendered, and the form is being shown for the second time now. Now, that you log in for the second time, the Log In controller will redirect you to https://www.example.com/refunds/polizza, as there intended route does not exists, and it uses the default route which is correctly set to `/polizza`.

### How to resolve this issue?

In your controller's constructor, change the line with:

```php
$this->middleware('auth')->except(['index']);
```

This way, you will exclude the index function from the auth middleware and it can be accessible to the public. The request should no longer redirect you to the default log in page. Now, going to https://www.example.com/refunds/ will just render a log in form, as you specified in your controller. When you log in with that form, it will take you to `/polizza` route.

Comment: Hi, i resolved by deleting this  public function index(){
  return view('auth.login');
 } from Refunds controller and add this to web routes Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});

Comment: I thought it gives me the same result which is the differences? Doing that it never redirects me to https://www.example.com/refunds/login when i go to https://www.example.com/refunds/

Comment: Please read Laravel's documentation on authentication https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication. If you put that route directly in your routes file like that, the route is not protected by any middleware and hence won't do any redirects as it is accessible to the public.

Comment: yes ok i think it is not a problem if just login page is accessible to the public in this case...or could be some risk? u always need a login and pass to enter the site

Comment: Of course it's not an issue. Log in page is always accessible to the public. How could anybody log in if they can't access the log in page? It is important to protect the routes that are just for logged in users. Please accept this answer if you found it helpful and if it resolved your issue. Thanks!

Comment: ok yes it was very helpfull! so just to know my solution do the same of urs technically?  thx a lot

Comment: Yes, but it is not advisable and it is not a good practice to put actual callback functions inside your routes file. Each route should lead to a controller method where it will be handled. So, yes, your solution does the same thing, but it's not good practice. I'm glad I was helpful! :)